# can i use the type secure text activity without using the get credentials activity?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

I am new to uipath and i am struck with automating our college website login. I am suggested to use the **"type secure text**" activity to secure the password that has to be entered in the password field. but it was not present in activity panel. youtube tutorials are suggesting to use the assets section in the orchestrator followed by get credential.

***Is that possible to secure the password with "Type secure text" without using the "get credential" activity and "assets section" in the orchestrator  ?***

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you trying to get the password as a SecureString? Or type it out from a SecureString?

Comment: trying to get the password as a secure string

Comment: Credential as asset is a good way to store your password. Otherwise you should have anothet credential store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use secure passwords or let's say credentials:

1. [Orchestrator Assets](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/managing-assets-in-studio)
2. [Windows Credentials](https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/how-to-work-with-windows-credentials)

As both are very well documented, it should be fine to just link to them here.

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes, you can use "type secure text" activity without get credential or asset section.

You will need to create a new variable of type SecureString and pass it as an argument to type secure text:

```
mystring = your string

newsecurestring = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(“”, “myString”)).SecurePassword
```

Then pass `newsecurestring` to type secure text activity.